# How does $W\frac YA[(\frac a{1-a})\frac WR]^{-a}+R\frac YA[(\frac a{1-a})\frac WR]^{1-a}$ become $\frac YA(\frac W{1-a})^{1-a}(\frac Ra)^a $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I really didn't understand how I can rearrange the second equation to get the third one. Can someone help me? It's a total cost function,  but the only thing I want is understand how the rearrangement was done.

Equation (18) is:
$$ K_j,_t = \frac{Y_j,_t}{A_t}\left[\left(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right) \frac{W_t}{R_t} \right]^{1-\alpha} $$

Equation (19):
$$ L_j,_t = \frac{Y_j,_t}{A_t}\left[\left(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right) \frac{W_t}{R_t} \right]^{-\alpha} $$
About the difference between the subscripts I think it is some typo.

Comment: If you [edit] the question to show us how far you got and where you are stuck we may be able to help. I suspect there is more context, since the left sides of the two equations differ. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It's weird that the subscript on the left-hand side changes, but the right-hand sides *are* equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd like to say that rearranging expressions varies and the intent matters. So in my attempt, I was really only trying to move variables around until it looked somewhat like the result shown. Therefore, I can't really tell you the exact steps the author took to get their result, but I can show you my attempt.

$$W_t \frac{Y_{j, t}}{A_t}[(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha})\frac{W_t}{R_t}]^{-\alpha} + R_t \frac{Y_{j, t}}{A_t}[(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha})\frac{W_t}{R_t}]^{1-\alpha} = $$

$$\frac{Y_{j, t}}{A_t}(W_t [(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha})\frac{W_t}{R_t}]^{-\alpha} + R_t [(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha})\frac{W_t}{R_t}]^{1-\alpha}) = $$

$$\frac{Y_{j, t}}{A_t}(W_t \frac{1}{[(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha})\frac{W_t}{R_t}]^{\alpha}} + R_t \frac{(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha})\frac{W_t}{R_t}}{[(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha})\frac{W_t}{R_t}]^{\alpha}}) = $$

$$\frac{Y_{j, t}}{A_t}(\frac{W_t + (\frac{W_t R_t}{R_t})(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha})}{[(\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha})\frac{W_t}{R_t}]^{\alpha}})  = \frac{Y_{j, t}}{A_t}(\frac{W_t(1+\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha})}{[(\frac{W_t}{1-\alpha})(\frac{\alpha}{R_t})]^{\alpha}}) = \frac{Y_{j, t}}{A_t}(\frac{\frac{W_t}{1-\alpha}}{(\frac{W_t}{1-\alpha})^{\alpha}(\frac{\alpha}{R_t})^{\alpha}}) = $$

$$\frac{Y_{j, t}}{A_t} (\frac{\frac{W_t}{1-\alpha}}{(\frac{W_t}{1-\alpha})^{\alpha}}) (\frac{1}{(\frac{\alpha}{R_t})^{\alpha}}) = \frac{Y_{j, t}}{A_t} (\frac{W_t}{1-\alpha})^{1-\alpha} (\frac{R}{\alpha})^{\alpha} $$

A few key points:

$\Large\frac{a^{b}}{a^{c}} = a^{b-c}$, and

$\Large\frac{1}{(\frac{a}{b})^{c}} = (\frac{1}{\frac{a}{b}})^{c}=(\frac{b}{a})^{c}$

I'd recommend simplifying everything down, then seeing how things fit together nicely in accordance to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Nice work! Thanks a lot!